# Hide/Show Div with coffeescript - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, registration, show-hide

There aren't many websites which give such fine tutorials on how to use coffee script to show or hide a div. The thing I want to do is: 
I have a div which is shaped like a button, linked_to a user_registration path with Devise.
I want to show a div right besides the button where the user can sign up and do their stuff.
So basically I'm interested if you have any idea on how to make for example, this  show up besides the ?

Answer (score 0):

use toogle

```
$('#target').toggle ->  alert 'First handler for .toggle() called.', ->  alert 'Second handler for .toggle() called.
```